# Неправильное описание в «Явно не по теме»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, перевод

В описании тревоги «Явно не по теме» написано:

> Этот вопрос не имеет ничего общего с русский язык.

Думаю правильней было бы:

> Этот вопрос не имеет ничего общего с сайтом «Русский язык».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо! Исправил формулировку на:

> Сайт «$имя сайта$» не подходящее место для вопроса.